# Java imported .jar file but jar's class objects cannot resolved

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am trying to send data via usb with Java.And I decided to use the **jSerialComm** library. I downloaded the required jar file and imported it correctly.
The whole code :

```
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;
public class Try{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SerialComm ports[] = SerialComm.getCommPorts();
    }
}
```

There is no problem with this row :

```
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;
```

But there is a problem here :

```
SerialComm ports[] = SerialComm.getCommPorts();
```

Error message : **SerialComm cannot be resolved to a type.**
And this is advice : **Create class 'SerialComm'**

Comment: You have imported the `SerialPort` class, not the `SerialComm` class.  Import the `SerialComm` class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should import this way :

```
    import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialComm
```

you could check out this if you want to more information :[instalation](https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm/wiki/Installation)

[look at this is a example of send data via usb with Java](https://github.com/mschoeffler/arduino-java-serial-communication/blob/master/example02_print_text_to_serial_monitor_with_USBtoTTLModule/java_send_text/src/de/mschoeffler/arduino/serialcomm/example02/Startup.java)

check out this :[jSerialComm/package-summary](http://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/javadoc/com/fazecast/jSerialComm/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 1):

You

```
    import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort
```

But not

```
    import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialComm
```

Answer (score 0):

SearialPort class is different than SerialComm, you need to import SerialComm class as well.
If you couldn't find it, it means your jar file is not compatible with your snippet code.

Comment: But I downloaded this jar from official web site and I can't find another jar for this libarary thanks for your comment.

Comment: What is the jar name

Comment: Try import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.*

Comment: jSerialComm-2.0.2.jar

Comment: The class is called SerialPort, not SerialComm
http://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/javadoc/com/fazecast/jSerialComm/SerialPort.html#getCommPorts--

Comment: Thanks I think my tutorial source is faulty.